# Are there any issues when installing apache tomcat with apache webserver already installed under Windows 7?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I am currently trying to install apache tomcat for running on localhost as I am planning to run a new development project using Java.

Will this be a problem if I have already apache webserver installed locally on my machine already?  In other words, will there be any port conflicts or anything other issues with the two servers running on the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Because Tomcat uses default port 8080 for the webserver while the "normal" webserver uses port 80 for html displaying. You can change that in the catalina properties of the tomcat server but on first install the defaults are not causing problems with a port 80 webserver.